# How to get item value from an ArrayCollection?

Tags: actionscript-3

I trying to read a value from an ArrayCollection, I use getItemAt and get an object:

`masterData.getItemAt(0,0)`

Then i use: `masterData.getItemAt(0,0).toString();` and get:

`<d>
    <i>The value that I need</i>
</d>`

Now How can I get the value in "< i >" tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert string to XML ( if all of your items will pass format of XML )
and then retrieve what you need.

```
var xml:XML = XML ( masterData.getItemAt(0,0).toString() );
trace( xml.i )
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach you can try is to parse the string you've been returned.

```
var theString:String = '<d> <i>The value that I need</i> </d>';
var startPosition = theString.search('<i>') + '<i>'.length;
var endPosition = theString.search('</i>');
trace (theString.substring(startPosition, endPosition));
```

In the code example above, which is overly verbose, I used a search for the postions of the substring because I didn't know the structure of the data you're expecting back.